# FileOutputStream Java

Tags: javascript, pdf, stream, byte

How can I fetch byte stream from a pdf file so that I can use that in FileOutputStream.write()?

Below is my code in js:

```
    $('input[name=file]').change(function(){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function() {
        var arrayBuffer = this.result,
        array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer),
        binaryString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, array);
        console.log(binaryString);
        document.getElementById("fileValue").value=binaryString;
    
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);
                
    });
object.fileValue    =fileValue;
```

I want to do like this:

```
FileOutputStream stream=new FileOutputStream(path+fileName,true);
stream.write(Integer.valueOf(taskIdListObj.getFileValue())); //byte stream from js
stream.close();
```

I am unable to do it. Is it really possible to do?

Comment: Wait a sec.. opening lines sounds java but your snippet is in jquery/javascript!. Please explain what you want in plain english rather than giving confusing analogies

Comment: I want to upload a pdf file in jsp, send the byte stream in java end and write into another pdf file with the help of FileOutputStream.write. I want to store the byte stream in js variable and send the variable to java end to write.